# Standard Deviation vs. Standard Error of the mean

Tags: standard-deviation, structural-equation-modeling

In a medical drug test, which one is reasonable to report along with mean to summarize the variance? SD or SEM?

Comment: Could you be more specific what you want to ask? The standard error of the mean IS a standard deviation.

Comment: My question is in a medical drug test, which one is reasonable to report along with mean to summarize the variance? SD or SEM?

Comment: http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?stat_standard_deviation_and_standar.htm

Answer (score 2):

The standard error IS the standard deviation of the sample mean.

Comment: So for variability it should be Mean and SD. Am I right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by variability. If you want to find the confidence interval of the population mean then you should use the sample mean and its standard error.